# Mulithreading hangs when used with requests module and large number of threads

Tags: python, multithreading, parallel-processing, python-requests, threadpool

I have about 2000 urls that I am trying to scrape using the `requests` module. To speed up the process, I am using the `ThreadPoolExecutor` from `concurrent.futures`. The execution hangs in the middle when I run this and the issue is inconsistent too. Sometimes, it finishes smoothly within 2 minutes but other times, it just gets stuck at a point for over 30 mins and I eventually have to kill the process.

```
# scraper.py

def get_content(url):
    try:
        res = requests.get(url)
        res = res.content
        return res
    except:
        return ""
```

```
# main.py

from scraper import get_content

if __name__ == "__main__":

    # content > an empty list for output
    # urls > a list of urls
 
    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=1000) as executor:
        results = executor.map(get_content, urls)

    for res in results:
        content = content.append(res)

    print(content)
```

**I want to understand how to debug this. Why and where is it getting stuck? And also, why is it inconsistent?**

Comment: Don't use max_workers=1000 if you don't have enough ram, check the performance by increasing max_workers from 32, 64, 128…etc.

Comment: shouldn't `get_content` have `return res` ...?

Comment: @Janukasamaranyake RAM is not an issue. It only uses about 2GB of RAM out of 16GB. When it runs, it runs within 2-3 mins.

Comment: @Anentropic Sorry. That was a post error. Fixed it.

Comment: The behaviour described *could* be due to slow responses from some of the URLs. For test purposes you could try using a timeout on the request. Also, as @Janukasamaranyake suggest, 1,000 threads is an awfully big number unless you know for sure that your machine can cope. Better IMO to construct the executor without any parameters unless you're absolutely sure you realise the impact

Comment: My hunch is that the threads are getting blocked by each other or daemon threads are being created and not being shutdown properly could be causing the problem. But I don't know how to confirm/fix that.

Comment: @asanoop24 Why would they be daemon threads? I also notice that you don't check the HTTP status code after GET. Why is that?